Make non-moderator "move to chat" move all comments and work better with moderator "move to chat"
When 2 users post a few back-forth comments on a post, a user sees:

Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

If clicked, the comments are copied to a chatroom and an automatic comment is posted:

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The 2 main issues with this are:

It doesn't copy all comments. It just copies comments from 2 users (I think), so if more than 2 users are involved, it only copies some of the comments, potentially losing the context of what other comments are replying to.

If a moderator then moves the discussion to chat, it creates a new chatroom, with a link to the 2nd chatroom inside that chatroom, and potentially messages from the 1st chatroom that aren't in the 2nd, and messages from the 2nd that aren't in the 1st.
This is unavoidable to some extent, if before a mod moves the comments, the conversation continues in chat but people also leave more comments. But at the moment this is a problem by design: if people want to continue the discussion, they are supposed to do so in chat, but if they do so, it's likely that neither the chatroom nor the comments on the post contains all comments, and a moderator using their default tool to move comments to chat makes it a problem between chatrooms.


My suggestions are as follows:

The non-moderator "move to chat" should copy all comments on the post.

This chatroom should be treated similar to mod-created ones, so mods don't create a second chatroom.
Apparently "move to chat" is single use for moderators, which prevents additional usages, so we might consider this to be that one usage (although people want mods to be able to move additional comments to chat, which is related).
(Given that this is making use of existing functionality, this should be a fairly small change.)

Change the automatic comment to look similar to the automatic moderator comment which discourages further commenting.

Maybe attribute that comment to the Community user so that the person who created the chatroom can't just delete the link.

Change the name of the chatroom from "Discussion between X and Y" to "Discussion on [question/answer] by X", like it is when a moderator moves comments.


I considered posting all of these as separate feature requests, but they are quite interdependent: the 2nd point doesn't make much sense without the 1st, and much of the use case for the 1st entails 2nd, and the 3rd and 4th need the first 2 to make sense.
Obligatory link to related post: Should "move-to-chat" be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?

Obligatory note that the move-to-chat is incredibly easy to hit by accident on mobile. Making this one-shot or the comment impossible to remove would be quite a nuisance.

@MisterMiyagi Maybe it should ask for confirmation then?

If the prompt is made, it almost invariably should be used, confirmation steps are not worth the time to develop.

Why should everyone else's comments be dragged into some back-and-forth between two people?

@JonCuster The same thing happens when mods move comments to chat. Why do you consider that to be "dragged into some back-and-forth"? You aren't notified when this happens. You aren't notified of new messages in the chatroom. More often than not, no-one will reply to your comment at that point, even if (especially if) the conversation continues. Your comment will likely just be hidden away in the transcript of some chatroom.

Other than the point that the user-initiated tool should copy all comments to chat, I think this request does more harm than good. I can't honestly remember if it only copies the two users' comments or all of them, so it may be a moot point.
Mods benefit from having a second chance to move messages
Consider:

one person participating in the conversation is willing to go to chat but the other keeps chatting in the comments (and so they both do)
a different discussion ensued that warranted moving to chat
a mod wants to move comments to chat to archive the full comment thread rather than merely throwing it away, due to length.

None of this would be possible in cases where users had continued the conversation in chat if your request were completed.
The mod tool allows a lot more control, plus a more direct message of warning or even a comment lock for a short time to prevent additional messages. I don't see the value of making it impossible for those comments to be moved just because one user clicked a button to create a chat room.
The two chat room problem
I think your concern about having two rooms is a bit overstated. If the two rooms really should be one, it's not particularly complex for a mod to move/delete messages to kinda merge the two rooms. It's not perfect but, since most rooms never get used, this is usually as simple as just freezing the user-created room.
Additionally, sometimes having two rooms is good or wanted.
Users don't have the authority or tools needed if the message is more stern
The automatic comment for the mod action is stern and harsh because it's a warning that further discussion about the post should stop or move to chat while reminding users what comments can be used for. Mods have the ability to edit the comment to soften it or adjust what it says for the situation.
Allowing a user make similar statements, even attributed to the Community user, is problematic - particularly since the average user will have no clue what clicking the continue discussion in chat button will do and probably doesn't want such a message to be created. Plus, if it is attributed to Community, they can't edit it to adjust the message.

Sorry, I just don't see the benefits of this considering the negative impact on mod's use of their tools.

If the "add to chat" feature request is implemented, mods would have that second chance (and further chances). But I can appreciate that it isn't currently implemented. And having a mod move messages between chatrooms seems like more effort than it's worth for most individual cases, but fixing the underlying design problem would fix all* cases. The "user will have no clue what the button will do" could be fixed by telling the user in the message or add a link. As it stands, the result of clicking that is already somewhat unexpected for a new user
